# undefined reference to `GradeBook::GradeBook(std::string)

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie for C++, I'm currently learning it with the book C++ How To Program 8e. In the section Separating Interface from Implementation they have given an example like this

### GradeBook.h

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class GradeBook
{
public:
    GradeBook( string );
    void setCourseName( string );
    string getCourseName();
    void displayMessage();
private:
    string courseName;
};
```

### GradeBook.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GradeBook.h"
using namespace std;

GradeBook::GradeBook( string name )
{
    setCourseName( name );
}

void GradeBook::setCourseName( string name )
{
    courseName = name;
}

string GradeBook::getCourseName()
{
    return courseName;
}

void GradeBook::displayMessage()
{
    cout << "welcome to the grade book for\n" << getCourseName()
        << "!" << endl;
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GradeBook.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    GradeBook gradeBook1( "CS101 Introduction to C++ Programming" );
    GradeBook gradeBook2( "CS102 Data Structures in C++" );

    cout << "gradeBook1 created for: " << gradeBook1.getCourseName()
        << "\ngradeBook2 created for: " << gradeBook2.getCourseName()
        << endl;
}
```

When I'm executing this with CodeBlocks I get an error with following info

```
D:\C++\SIFI\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `GradeBook::GradeBook(std::string)'|
D:\C++\SIFI\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `GradeBook::GradeBook(std::string)'|
D:\C++\SIFI\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `GradeBook::getCourseName()'|
D:\C++\SIFI\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `GradeBook::getCourseName()'|
||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I'm an absolute newbie and please help.

Comment: You need to link both `cpp` files in the build. I don't know CodeBlocks, but presumably you're building a "project" or something; make sure you've added both files to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Code::Blocks bug... Sometimes, your cpp files are not added to your project, you have to add it by yourself to your project. (something like "file > add file > existing file"?)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using codeblocks then you have to create a project first. After creating the project , just open the project column from the above tabs and click add files. Then add all of you're main , .h, .cpp files in it. Now compile it and done!

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using the plain GNU Fortran compiler, rather than some IDE such as CodeBlocks, this would be the command line:

```
g++ main.cpp GradeBook.cpp -o main.x
```